# Filtering lookup values based on another column in another list, sharepoint online and powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp

I need to filter a column in the list A, in her form. The filtered values must exist in the list B and I need do this in the form of powerapps. It's simple to do this in SharePoint 2013, but I cant do this in powerapps.

I'm trying do this:

```
Filter(Choices([@ListA].Diretoria);Value in Filter(ListB;ReferenceFilter.Empresa=DataCardValue3.SelectedItems).Title)
```

but I cant read the ListB.

List B

[image]

Ex: When I select the Empresa 1 in the field DataCardValue3 in the form of the list A, I need filter to show just values of Diretoria A and C.

Someone can help me?

Comment: What's the relation between the List A and List B?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the configuration of the lists and also fields you use in the formula? Are these column names you use in the two lists - *Diretoria*, *Empresa*, *ReferenceFilter*?

Comment: The list B have the column Empresa and the DataCardValue3have the same values, I need select 1 of all values in list B have the same Empresa record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have successfull doing this:

1 - Add list b as datasource
2 - Do the filteer by ID

Filter(Choices([@Divisao].Diretoria);Id in Filter(Diretoria;Empresa.Id=DataCardValue9.Selected.Id).ID) (in pt-br we use ';' and not ',')

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula:

```
DataCardValue3.Items = Filter(Choices([@ListA].Diretoria),Value in Filter(ListB,DataCardValue2.Selected.Value=Empresa).Title)
```

*DataCardValue2* is the data card for the Choice column *Empresa*.

*DataCardValue3* is the data card for the Lookup column *Diretoria*

[image]

Comment: When I use [@ListA] I have a error, it seems that the name is not associated with the list, the only list that is found is the current list where I am modifying the form.

Comment: I have successful to add the data source of list B, but the filter not working :(

Comment: Filter(Choices([@Divisao].Diretoria);Value in Filter(Diretoria;DataCardValue9.Selected.Value=Empresa.Value).Title) the code run, bu the itens not filtered, all is showed

Comment: I have sucesseful doing this Filter(Choices([@Divisao].Diretoria);Id in Filter(Diretoria;Empresa.Id=DataCardValue9.Selected.Id).ID)

Comment: @DiegoHillesheim Glad to know you solved your problem. You can mark your own Answer so that it will help others in this forum as well. Thanks.