# Filtering lookup values based on another column powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, lookup-column, cascading, cascading-dropdown

I have a document library (with document sets). And while I wanted to use enterprise metatags (so I can use nested tags) the users feel that this is too much of a confusion and would like to have two columns where the second would be filtered based on the first. I thought of using powerapps and followed plenty of examples like this one https://www.portiva.nl/portiblog/2018/11/09/creating-conditional-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-with-powerapps
but it seems like an overkill to have two sharepoint lists while I could have one.
I found this topic: [Filtering lookup values based on another column in another list, sharepoint online and powerapps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288188/filtering-lookup-values-based-on-another-column-in-another-list-sharepoint-onli) but I can't decypher what is the logic behind the solution.
and if I just try to copy and paste (replacing names) I get constantly errors.

In my scenario, I have a sharepoint list called "Project Tags" with two columns. One is Document Category and the second Document Type with a 1:N relation.
Then I have the doc library where I thought of using a drop-down to represent the document categories and a lookup for the document type.

Now what I look to do is to filter the document type, based on the value of the document category. If needed, I can replace the drop-down with a lookup.

Anyone kind enough to help me out with this?

Comment: I also found this solution 
http://blog.extrobe.co.uk/blog/2016/11/27/populate-a-dropdown-based-on-the-value-of-another-dropdown-in-powerapps/ but again I have no luck in filtering the lookup field using the value of the first drop-down

Answer (score 0):

For PowerApps, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo) which may be an easy option for you. You will need to first set up a source list for the relationship between Document Category and Document type(just like the region and country in the video). And then in the actual list, single text column will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the link. I had found the same video, but the options they get on the video, I don't have. (see allowed values as a field type). But the principle stands true.

Answer (score 0):

I have found various solutions to this,

https://youtu.be/pkZG2boN7jQ?t=524

http://blog.extrobe.co.uk/blog/2016/11/27/populate-a-dropdown-based-on-the-value-of-another-dropdown-in-powerapps/

[Filtering lookup values based on another column in another list, sharepoint online and powerapps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288188/filtering-lookup-values-based-on-another-column-in-another-list-sharepoint-onli)

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/filter-a-person-column-based-on-another-column/td-p/588416

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo

now, my only problem is that the form is not saving after the changes. will get there.